# While trying to launch Chrome from Mac system I am getting error. cannot find Chrome binary

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Initially, I have tried with below code and got above error.

```py
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/mousumi/Documents/Workspace_python/Drivers/chromedriver')
 driver.get("www.google.com")


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/mousumi/Documents/Workspace_python/Drivers/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options,service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=/tmp/chromedriver.log’])
```

Now, I am getting below error:

```
/Users/mousumi/PycharmProjects/Selenium/venv/bin/python /Users/mousumi/Documents/Workspace_python/SeleniumUdemy/Chrome_driver_demo.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mousumi/Documents/Workspace_python/SeleniumUdemy/Chrome_driver_demo.py", line 18, in <module>
    cc.test()
  File "/Users/mousumi/Documents/Workspace_python/SeleniumUdemy/Chrome_driver_demo.py", line 13, in test
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/Users/mousumi/Documents/Workspace_python/Drivers/chromedriver.exe', options=chrome_options,service_args=['--verbose', '--log-path=/tmp/chromedriver.log'])
NameError: name 'chrome_options' is not defined
```

Can someone please help. It’a blocker for me

Comment: This is hard to read. Please edit your post and put 3 tick marks above and below your code to format it.

Comment: does the executable exist at that path location and it's permissions are set correctly?

Comment: how you set `chrome_options` variable?seems like it's not defined